# Buy second-hand bike in or near Frankfurt

Tags: commuter, germany

I'm travelling to Frankfurt, Germany in the next month and I'll be staying there for three months, because my trip is related to work, I'm trying to know how to get a bike that I can use to commute, (My daily commute is to get to Bad Homburg) taking into account that my german knowledge is almost none (even thought I'm learning by myself right now), and I don't know how english (spanish or french) comunication is in the aforementioned city. I'd like to know what are the best known places in or near Frankfurt to get a second hand bike. It doesn't have to be a pro one, nothing fancy, I just want something useful at a reasonable price.

Comment: In and near Frankfurt you will find many people with whom you can communicate fairly well in English. It depends very much on their educational background. Nearly every university student will be fluent. All secondary education requires at least one foreign language, which is most of the time English, sometimes French or Spanish.

University students also ride used bikes a lot, and might know where to get them. If you arrive, have a walk in the inner city, and ask a group of students with bikes. (People also bike home after clubs and parties.)

Comment: This is a shopping question and is of limited longterm value.  As such its off topic for this site.

Comment: I considered a question on the procedure of finding a used bike to buy in Germany. Advise to check eg eBay or local classifieds will not change very much over the course of a few years, and is transferable to other German cities.

Comment: @gschenk https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic   specifically "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."  This is "how do I get a bike for a couple months in Frankfurt?" which might be more on topic for travel.SE    A rental could be a good solution, but we don't want a list of rental companies in the answer.  Buying a folding bike could solve OP's problem too  [Rule #12](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#12)

Comment: @gschenk Consider the answer "Use the nextbike rental bikes - there are 30 stations and 200 bikes in Frankfurt"  which is correct as of February 2017.   The scheme may change by the time OP gets there.   An answer of "go to http://www.hexhex-fahrraeder.de/ " again may change over time.  SE is about building long-term useful answers.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @jecarfor. We recommend the new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site. As Criggie said, we think this one is off topic, and will be closed. Meanwhile, gschenk is in Germany has given pretty good advice. My thought would be to ask people in the company in Germany to help. They may even have a cycling social group that can help.

Answer (score 2):

I actually grew up near Bad Homburg, and have bought a used bike there. (You do realize that depending on where in Frankfurt you want to go, the way there from Bad Homburg can be quite far?) The two biggest bike shops there are [Fahrrad Denfeld](http://www.denfeld.de/) and [Fahrrad Diehl](http://www.fahrraddiehl.de/). At least some years ago, both of these shops sold used bikes as well, and for reasonable prices. I think I bought one from Fahrrad Diehl for 150€ that I used during my 5 years of studying

Communicating in English should not be a problem in either Bad Homburg or Frankfurt, especially with people from "younger" generations / who are < 50 years old

Answer (score 1):

### A few German expressions that might help you in your search:

- Bicycle in general: Fahrrad
- Road bike with drop bars: Rennrad
- Mountainbike: Mountainbike
- Folding bike: Faltrad, Klapprad
- Cruiser bikes: Hollandrad
- 3-Speed: 3-Gang-Rad
- Cyclocross bike: Crossrad, Querfeldeinrad (almost obsolete), Querrad,
  Radcross-Rad
- Hybrid bike: this gets difficult, as it might sometimes called
  Hybrid,m Crossbike, ATB (for all terrain bike) or some improvised
  name or description.
- Singlespeed and Fixie became fashionable in Germany as well; typically the English terms are used as well.

Note that the compound words may also be hyphenated: eg *Crossrad* is the same as *Cross-Rad*, and even *Cross Rad* (which is incorrect but not infrequent).

Regional or Colloquial Terms for Fahrrad are
*Velo* (Switzerland), *Radl* (Bavaria and Austria), *Rad* (otherwise).
The somewhat out fashioned colloquial expressions Drahtesel and *Stahlross* might still be used, typically for sturdy old bikes.

### Names of Components and Features

- Brake: Bremse
- Gears, speeds: Schaltung, Gangschaltung, Gänge
- Gearhub: Nabenschaltung
- Handlebars: Lenker
- Mudguards: Schutzbleche
- Disc brake: Scheibenbremse
- Derailleur: Umwerfer
- Drop bars: Rennlenker
- Rack: Gepäckträger
- Wheel set: Laufradsatz LRS

Comment: Why is this a Community Wiki?  Its totally off topic.

Comment: Are there special requirements for an answer to be handed to the community? I thought one would only rescind the points earned from up votes while allowing edits without review?

Comment: CW posts are ones where voting on the best answer is not   suitable.  [More info here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)   Our glossary of bike terms, or the "frame materials" CW posts are good examples of where there isn't an answer, and the whole corpus of replies is useful.  Also edits are much easier, and upvotes on answers/replies do not accrue to the answerer.